# How to apply css on table header of Material ui Table stickyHeader?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI table with stickyHeader prop as i want my table header to be fixed. But then other css is not applying on the header part.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    tableHead: {
    borderBottomStyle: "solid",
    borderBottomColor: "blue",
  },
}))


const CustomTable = () => {
return(
<TableContainer component={Paper} className={classes.tableContainer}>
    <Table stickyHeader aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead classes={{ root: classes.tableHead }}>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Hii</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
    </Table>
</TableContainer>
)
}
```

**When I am removing "stickyHeader" props. I am getting blue border at the bottom of header but not in case of stickyHeader.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by adding the props `stickyHeader` a class gets added which sets the `border-collapse:separate`. this needs to be removed for the header border to be visible.
Target the `stickyHeader` Mui class from `Table`.

```
<TableContainer component={Paper} className={classes.tableContainer}>
    <Table stickyHeader classes={{stickyHeader:classes.stickyHeader}} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead classes={{ root: classes.tableHead }}>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Hii</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
    </Table>
</TableContainer>
```

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    tableHead: {
        borderBottomStyle: "solid",
        borderBottomColor: "blue"
    },
    stickyHeader:{
        borderCollapse:'collapse'
    }
}));
```

### Update

To make the border to be fixed, there's a workaround is that just add a `borderBottom` in the `TableCell` of the `TableHead`.

```
<Table stickyHeader aria-label="simple table">
    <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
            <TableCell
                style={{
                    borderBottom: "5px solid blue"
                }}
            >
                Hii
            </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
    <TableBody>
        {//Tablebody items}
    </TableBody>
</Table>
```

Working demo:
[image: Edit gallant-euler-5p4rn]

Comment: Yes, Now i can see the blue border but the border is also getting scrolled.

Comment: How to stick that blue border with the header?

Comment: Nope! The border is still scrolling

Comment: have you checked the codesandbox demo??? In this case, there's no need to add any style for border-collapse or anything..

Comment: Oh! I didn't notice that! Yes, i just saw it. It is working perfectly in CodeSandBox. I'll check it in my code tomorrow. Thank You so much for your help. I'm marking this as Answer as of now! Will let u know if i face and difficulty once i check it in my code.

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer for MUI 5 as I had the same issue - anytime I would set the `stickyHeader` prop for my `<Table>` my styling would go away.

I targeted the `MuiTableCell-root` class in my `TableHead` component and it was just fine.

Example with styled-components:

```
export const StyledTableHead = styled(TableHead)`
  & .MuiTableCell-root {
    background-color: red;
  }
`;
```

It appears that in the `stickyHeader` prop will not function as intended without first setting a `maxHeight` for the `<Table>` in the `<TableContainer>`.

Example with styled-components:

```
export const StyledTableContainer = styled(TableContainer)`
  border-top-left-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.3rem;
  max-height: 500px;
`;
```

This could then be used like so:

```
<StyledTableContainer>
  <Table stickyHeader>
    <StyledTableHead>
      <TableRow>
        [your table header cells here]
      </TableRow>
    </StyledTableHead>
  </Table>
</StyledTableContainer>
```